# The specified method is not allowed against this resource in Amazon aws

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, smartfoxserver

Guys I may or may not be wrong, But seriously, I am struggling with file uploading problem in Amazon S3 bucket. When I am trying to hit on the request then I am getting the following error.

> **MethodNotAllowed** and **The specified method is not allowed against this resource**

The above message is the sort of the below response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>MethodNotAllowed</Code
<Message>Thespecified method is not allowed against this resource.</Message>
<Method>POST</Method><ResourceType>OBJECT</ResourceType>
<RequestId>xxx</RequestId><HostId>xxxx</HostId></Error>
```

The above message is the complete message and below is the code whatever I have written for uploading files to amazon s3 server.

```
public synchronized boolean uploadFile(String url, String name, File file) {
    HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .addPart("file", new FileBody(file)).build();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    request.setEntity(entity);
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            try (InputStream in_stream = entity.getContent()) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in_stream));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder responseBuffer = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseBuffer.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                String a = responseBuffer.toString();
                Utils.print("\n\n" + a + "\n\n");
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Utils.print(e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please suggest me what to do for this? I will be very thankful for your expected answer.

Comment: You seem to be using a `POST` request, it might be that the resource you are uploading to expects a `PUT` request. Could try by changing the `HttpPost` to a `HttpPut`

Answer (score 2):

You could be getting MethodNotAllowed, which recommends using an identity that belongs to the bucket owner's account.

> If you have the correct permissions, but you're not using an identity that belongs to the bucket owner's account, Amazon S3 returns a 405 Method Not Allowed error.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketPolicy.html

from a list of S3 API error responses

> The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html